# Is there any reason not to model group medians with a plain regression model?

Tags: regression, median, aggregation

Consider the [Boston Housing dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing), in which the intended target/response $Y$ is actually a group median.

Are there any objections to modeling this group median with a standard regression model, in which the model inputs $X$ affect $Y$ only through its conditional mean $E[Y|X]$? If so, what is the preferred alternative?